# Neo4j: configure legacy index with cypher or property file

Tags: indexing, neo4j

I am using Neo4j-server and I am trying to find a way to configure a legacy index either with cypher or with a property. So far to enable the legacy indexing I just uncommented the related line in neo4j.properties file. How can I apply some of the configurations listed [here](http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/indexing-create-advanced.html) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written some code that might be helpful: [neo4j-fti](https://github.com/sarmbruster/neo4j-fti)

It basically hooks into the startup process and creates manual indexes with customizable analyzers.

Comment: This is possible only with manual indexes? Is there an alternative using auto indexing?

Comment: auto index (there is only one for nodes and rels) is basically a manual index using a naming convention 'node_auto_index' that gets updated by a internal transaction event handler. So if you use neo4j-fti and set a analyzer for index `node_auto_index` it should work. Be aware that this only works if the index does not exist beforehand.